# IntelliJ ignores JUnit 5

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5

I have a multi module maven project with a lots of JUnit5 based tests. On the command line everything works fine and all tests are executed.

However IntelliJ behaves like there is not JUnit dependency. All JUnit imports and code usages are marked red:

[image: imports]

[image: assertions]

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Anything interesting in the problems panel?

Comment: No. Just a gazillion "Cannot resolve symbol ..." entries.

Comment: Include junit5 as project dependency. Also "sync" with maven->right click pom-> maven-> reimport project

Comment: As already mentioned. The pom.xml is fine and `mvn clean install` is executing >1000 unit tests without any problems, no matter if run maven on CLI, inside IntelliJ or on Jenkins. It's just IntelliJ somehow ignoring JUnit.

Comment: Check the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html). See also https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea .

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache and restarting?

Comment: Unfortunately invalidating the Caches and restarting does not help. All tests remain red.

Comment: Did you try to right-click in all `POM`s and do `Maven` -> `Reload project`? If yes and it didn't help you, could you elaborate, what is exact maven dependency for `Junit` version and what version of `Intellij IDEA` you're using for it now? Need more details how to reproduce it.

Comment: Have you up-to-date versions of IntelliJ and JUnit? Maybe your pom.xml has some irrgularities so you might want to add it to the code.

Comment: After all just marking *all* modules and then right click->Maven->Reload Project did the trick. Thanks @invzbl3, feel free to add your comment as an answer to get the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, to solve the issue:

```
"Cannot resolve symbol ..."
```

with imports, you can right-click in `POM` and do `Maven` -> `Reload project`:

[image]

For more details you can refer, for instance, to this [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport).